# ResourceEntries RVAs of a Resource Table need relocation upon copying it to a different image/PE?

Tags: x86, disassembly, portable-executable

I've succesfully built a basic JAVA disassembler, simply because the already built open source one (pecoff4j and its forks) didn't help despite being excellent.
I've already managed to **parse all the PE header**, compared it to Lord PE and PE Explorer, and everything seems to be in place, at least for x86 executables.
I'm doing this for a certain reason. I want to **copy the Resource Directory of the PE to another PE**. I (try to) do this by first parsing everything in the header until all my variables are populated. I will take LORD PE executable as an example. Below is the 3rd directory entry, aka the resource directory.

```
ResourceDirectorySize: 0x16E50, ResourceDirectoryVirtualAddress: 0x1F000
```

I keep these values in mind, and proceed with the section header parsing.
First section is this:

```
Name: .text
VirtualSize: 0x000172D0
Virtualaddress: 0x00001000
SizeOfRawData: 0x00017400
PointedToRawData: 0x00000400
```

...
And eventually reach to the one I need:

```
Name: .rsrc
VirtualSize: 0x00016E50
Virtualaddress: 0x0001F000
SizeOfRawData: 0x00017000
PointedToRawData: 0x0001C000
```

Since the VirtualSize and VirtualAddress are the same as the ones I mentioned above, I decide this is the resource table. So I blindly copy the range `0x1C000 to 0x33000` to the other executable, and also update the ResourceDirectorySize and VirtualAddress of the PE header.

I also update several other things, like size of image, initialized data, number of sections to reflect the new executable state.

---

**And my question**: Do the `ResourceEntries` need to be relocated in order to reflect the new Virtual Address of the ResourceDirectory?

Comment: why the negative vote? What is this question missing?

Comment: Can you highlight and or summarize your specific question, separate from all the background info?  Oh, there it is all the way at the very end, buried inside a large paragraph where a few other words are randomly bolded.  That is the opposite of skimable.

Comment: @PeterCordes I assume you understood where the question lies then, do you have anything to add regarding the question itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Resource Directory containing internal `PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY` structures:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY {
    DWORD   OffsetToData;
    DWORD   Size;
    DWORD   CodePage;
    DWORD   Reserved;
} IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY, *PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY;
```

the `OffsetToData` member is actually `RVA` - so relative offset from image base (when file mapped as image). if you copy resource directory to new image - you need fix `OffsetToData` fields in all `IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY`. so resource directory must be **relocated** to new `RVA`.

let we have:

- `oldRVA` - *rva* where *rsrc* placed in current image.
- `newRVA` - *rva* where *rsrc* will be placed in new image.

so we need fix `OffsetToData = newRVA + (OffsetToData - oldRVA)` or

```
DWORD Diff = newRVA - oldRVA; // calc once
OffsetToData += Diff;
```

so code for copy rsrc can be next

```
void RelocateRSRC(PBYTE prsrc, PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY pird, LONG Delta)
{
    if (DWORD NumberOfEntries = pird->NumberOfNamedEntries + pird->NumberOfIdEntries)
    {
        PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY pirde = (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY)(pird + 1);

        do 
        {
            if (pirde->DataIsDirectory)
            {
                RelocateRSRC(prsrc,
                    (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY)(prsrc + pirde->OffsetToDirectory),
                    Delta);
            } 
            else 
            {
                PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY data = 
                    (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY)(prsrc + pirde->OffsetToData);

                data->OffsetToData += Delta;
            }

        } while (pirde++, --NumberOfEntries);
    }
}

BOOL CopyRSRC(PVOID ImageBase, BOOLEAN MappedAsImage, ULONG NewRva, void** pprsrc)
{
    *pprsrc = 0;

    ULONG Size;
    if (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY pird = (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY)
        RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(ImageBase, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE, &Size))
    {
        NewRva -= RtlPointerToOffset(ImageBase, pird);

        if (!MappedAsImage)
        {
            pird = (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY)
                RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(ImageBase, FALSE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE, &Size);
        }

        if (PBYTE prsrc = new BYTE[Size])
        {
            *pprsrc = prsrc;
            memcpy(prsrc, pird, Size);
            RelocateRSRC(prsrc, (PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY)prsrc, NewRva);
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Judging* from your answer it seems there are no negative offset resources, and I can say the raw data of resources actually exist IN the resource section. I am building the ResourceParser right now as I've figured out it is impossible to get the RVA values blindly and change them. Let me finish the parser, change the values and reassemble the PE, I suspect this is the answer I wanted. I will accept it once everything is in place, and hopefully will help someone in the future. Thank you sir.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I parsed the Resource Tables, and reached to the leafs (Resource Data Entries) where I changed the RVA the way you told me. Everything is working. I change my question to a fitting one.